# Having some issues with % in a string in batch

Tags: batch-file

I've been trying to work on a batch file that will eventually work on reading in text that will contain a % in it. When doing some testing with variables that contain a % in them, I found that I'm getting some sort of error, but the window is closing to fast.

What's causing the error?

Test code

```
SET WIN="55.23%:"
echo %WIN%
:: This shows WIN but without the % on it, which I think is causing the error later on

SET TESTING=%WIN:~3%
echo %TESTING%
pause
```

Comment: Please report the specific error you're getting.

Comment: I can't give the error as the window closes so quickly that I can't read what its saying. >.<

Comment: Then reproduce the error in a window that doesn't close.

Comment: is this part of `IF` condition or `FOR` loop? Like this it will not produce an error , though you need to double the percentage in the first SET

Comment: you can see the error with calling the bat like `myBat.bat >log 2>&1` and error will be store in the `log` file.

Comment: How would I double the % on text being read in from a file? Like I said above the code is a test snippet for a different batch that I was going to be writing. How would I do that on windows 8?

Comment: @ThomasMorse - if it is red from file show more code.Probably the error is somewhere else.

Comment: You can have it not close the window by actually running it from a command prompt instead of double-clicking it in Explorer. So, asking again: **What is the specific error you're getting?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SET "WIN=55.23%%:"
```

The problem with your approach:

- (Inside a script) you must *double* `%` chars. for them to be treated as *literals* (without doubling, if the `%` is not part of a valid environment-variable reference, it is simply *removed*).
- Where you placed the double quotes - around the RHS only - caused them to become *part of the value*; to illustrate:

  ```
    SET "WIN=55.23%%:"
    :: %WIN% now contains >>>55.23%<<<
    SET WIN="55.23%%:"
    :: %WIN% now contains >>>"55.23%"<<< - INCLUDING the DOUBLE QUOTES
  ```

Comment: Ok that works. Now it actually works despite the single % in the string. I don't care that it's stripping the % from the the text, I just needed the text to be able to be used despite the % being in it, as the batch that I'm going to be writing will read in lines that have a % after the win chance.